# Is there a way to set this entity/linq query to IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, linq, casting, ienumerable, anonymous-types

I'm trying to return an IEnumerable activities instead of "var"

```
var activities = ctx.Activities.Where(a => a.SiteID == propID)
                 .Where(a => a.ActivityTypeName == "Call")
                 .Select(x => new
                 {
                   x.DateTimeEntry,
                   x.Contact.OwnerContact.ParcelDatas
                    .FirstOrDefault(a => a.OwnerContactID == x.Contact.OwnerContact.OOwnerID)
                    .Parcel_LetterTracking.LMailDate,
                   x.FAQs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ActivityID == x.ActivityID)
                    .FAQ_Library.FaqNum,
                   x.FAQs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ActivityID == x.ActivityID)
                    .FAQ_Library.Question
                 });
```

edit: data type Object compiles but I'm not sure if that's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.Select` already returns a an `IEnumerable<TResult>` also combine your .`.where()` clauses with `&&` instead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8 also one other thing you can do is use [.AsEnuemerable()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8)

```
 var activities = ctx.Activities.Where(a => a.SiteID == propID && a.ActivityTypeName == "Call")
                .Select(x => new 
                {                 
                    x.DateTimeEntry,
                    x.Contact.OwnerContact.ParcelDatas.FirstOrDefault(a => a.OwnerContactID == x.Contact.OwnerContact.OOwnerID).Parcel_LetterTracking.LMailDate,
                    x.FAQs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ActivityID == x.ActivityID).FAQ_Library.FaqNum,
                    x.FAQs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ActivityID == x.ActivityID).FAQ_Library.Question
            }).AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: I prefer AsEnumerable more because it's returning an IEnumerable instead of enumerator. Thank you!

Comment: No problem glad I could help.

Comment: @Neovssmith, what do you mean by "I prefer AsEnumerable more because it's returning an IEnumerable instead of enumerator"?

Comment: @PauloMorgado `GetEnumerator` implies he's iterating through the list, which might not be the case. Maybe he is returning something to the client and not iterating through the data?

Comment: `GetEnumerator()` creates an enumerator. Doesn't imply anything.

Comment: `Enumerable.AsEnumerable<T>()` just changes the compile-time type to `IEnumerable<T>`. Nothing else! [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.asenumerable?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,3ee4ab000402fbeb)

Comment: @PauloMorgado That's what he's asking for isn't he? I think you're missing the point of my post. He's already returning an `IEnumerable` but if he wants to he can convert a type by using `asEnumerable`. That was my point, have a good one!

Comment: GetEnumerator returns IEnumerator, which is fine but I wanted to use a foreach loop over an IEnumerable instead of in a while(movenext)